# How to create pdf file using html in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to generate a pdf file with text that will change every time based on my server data. I want to create that pdf file using html in iOS. Any suggestions. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

1. You need to show it on webview like this

   ```
   -(IBAction)convertPDF:(id)sender { 
   webViewHeight = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] integerValue];

       CGRect screenRect = self.myWebView.frame;

       double currentWebViewHeight = webViewHeight;
       while (currentWebViewHeight > 0)
       {
           imageName ++;

           UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

           CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
           [[UIColor blackColor] set];
           CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

           [self.myWebView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

           UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

           UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

           NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
           NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
           NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageName]];

           if(currentWebViewHeight < 960)
           {
               CGRect lastImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 960 - currentWebViewHeight, self.myWebView.frame.size.width, currentWebViewHeight);
               CGImageRef lastImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([newImage CGImage], lastImageRect);                
               newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:lastImageRef]; 
               CGImageRelease(lastImageRef);
           }

           [UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

           [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollBy(0,960);"];
           currentWebViewHeight -= 960;
       }
       [self drawPdf];
   }
   ```
2. then draw PDF from webview

   ```
    - (void) drawPdf
   { CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, webViewHeight);
   NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

   UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

   // Mark the beginning of a new page.
   UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

   double currentHeight = 0.0;

   for (int index = 1; index <= imageName ; index++)
   {
       NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", index]];
       UIImage *pngImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngPath];

       [pngImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, currentHeight, pageSize.width, pngImage.size.height)];        
       currentHeight += pngImage.size.height;
   }

   UIGraphicsEndPDFContext(); }
   ```
3. In viewDidLoad

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSString *path;
   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
   path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Demo" ofType:@"html"];

   NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/sites/overview.html"];
   [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl]];
   }
   ```

Comment: @vasu Let me know if it helps you.. I did it 3 years ago.. so pasted my code..

Comment: Hi Krishna kumar, thank you for reply. i'll let you know after i check this.

Comment: @VasuV you can modify the settings of webview as per your need..

Comment: Thank you Krishna Kumar , it's working .......

Comment: Glad that it worked..

Comment: Upvote it.. But I should not ask for it

Comment: Hi @KrishnaKumar , is this solution work for html with image? Thx~

Answer (score 2):

Please check below link :

https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf.

Its have methods for doing that with local html file as well as with URL also.

```
+ (id)createPDFWithHTML:(NSString*)HTML pathForPDF:(NSString*)PDFpath delegate:(id <NDHTMLtoPDFDelegate>)delegate pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize margins:(UIEdgeInsets)pageMargins;
+ (id)createPDFWithHTML:(NSString*)HTML baseURL:(NSURL*)baseURL pathForPDF:(NSString*)PDFpath delegate:(id <NDHTMLtoPDFDelegate>)delegate pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize margins:(UIEdgeInsets)pageMargins;
+ (id)createPDFWithHTML:(NSString*)HTML pathForPDF:(NSString*)PDFpath pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize margins:(UIEdgeInsets)pageMargins successBlock:(NDHTMLtoPDFCompletionBlock)successBlock errorBlock:(NDHTMLtoPDFCompletionBlock)errorBlock;
+ (id)createPDFWithHTML:(NSString*)HTML baseURL:(NSURL*)baseURL pathForPDF:(NSString*)PDFpath pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize margins:(UIEdgeInsets)pageMargins successBlock:(NDHTMLtoPDFCompletionBlock)successBlock errorBlock:(NDHTMLtoPDFCompletionBlock)errorBlock;
```

Comment: Hi darshan, thank you for reply. i'll let you know after i check this.